# How can I download iWork from App Store

Tags: mac-appstore, iwork

I have purchased iWork from an apple store couple of years ago. The software it has is the latest, same with those found on App Store. Is there anyway that I can make my account able to download Pages,Numbers and Keynote from the App Store? I do have the box of the software and even the receipt.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Maybe there is an acceptable alternative.

Comment: Nothing more than not having to depend on the disc for the installation. If I lost that disc I would lose the software.

Comment: You can use Disk Utility to make an ISO file of the disk. With an ISO, you can simply mount the file and it will function exactly as having the disc in a drive, or you can use the ISO file to burn a new disc at any time. Of course, this requires you to have a safe place to store the ISO file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn't offer a way to move iWork licenses to the App Store. There isn't much to gain from such a move anyway because new major releases of iWork have (at least til now) always be sold as full versions only (which still was cheaper than e.g. MS Office upgrade versions).